# rysnc on perl until loop never breaks

Tags: perl

I was having a difficulty about perl script..I have a script that includes a loop but never breaks out of it once it gets the exit status zero.The loop will run only once the exit status results a 1 upon checking initially by the "if" statement.

```
my $a = "/home/vivek/generated_mdsum_reference.out";
my $b = "/home/vivek/generated_mdsum_new.out";

sub CHECK {
    print "\n";
    print "\n";
    print "\n\tGenerating MD5SUM ....";
    my $dumpfile = "/home/vivek/file_dump.dmp";
    print "\n";
    # my $md5sum = system("md5sum $dumpfile");
    my $md5sum = `md5sum $dumpfile`;
    print "\n";
    print "\nChecksum: $md5sum.";
    # Put checksum in file
    my $ochksumfile = "/home/vivek/generated_mdsum_new.out";
    open (my $fh, '>', "$ochksumfile") or die "no file:$!";
    my $output = $md5sum;
    die "$!" if $?;
    $value = (split / /, "$output")[0];
    print $fh $value;
    my $status =compare($b, $a);
}

my $status =compare($b, $a);
if ( $status == 1 ){
    do
        CHECK;
    until ($status == 0 ) {
        print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..";
        print "\n\t";
    }
```

All the variables I have set in there works fine, I only ended up in the until loop which it keeps on running endlessly which I think it cannot get through until the rest of the function "CHECK"

Please help me guys.

Comment: Where is `compare` defined?

Comment: Also, do not use variables named $a and $b, as they have special meaning in perl:  perldoc -f sort

Comment: Perhaps you want to `CHECK until ($status == 0)` instead of `do CHECK; until ($status == 0)`   Have a look at `perldoc perlsyn` and read the `Compound Statements` section.

Comment: Why is `rsync` in the title? If you do this to check whether `rsync` has copied a file correctly, why not let `rsync` do that check?

Comment: I already did until ($status == 0)...same result guys

Comment: $a and $b is defined above, outside the function...does that make a difference guys?

Comment: @shadow: No. You should *never* use `$a` and `$b` in any circumstance to avoid confusion with the built-in `sort` variables. They are also a very poor choice of identifier as they convey nothing about the nature of their contents

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the block in question

```
my $status = compare($b, $a);
if ( $status == 1 ) {
    do
        CHECK;
    until ($status == 0 ) {
        print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..";
        print "\n\t";
    }
```

whether you meant it or not, this is equivalent to

```
my $status = compare($b, $a);

if ( $status == 1 ) {
    do  CHECK;

    until ( $status == 0 ) {
        print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..";
        print "\n\t";
    }
```

So the contents of your `until` loop is just two print statements, which aren't going to change the value of `$status` so it will loop forever
What I think you meant is

```
my $status = compare($b, $a);

if ( $status == 1 ) {

    do {
        CHECK;
    } until $status == 0;

    print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..";
    print "\n\t";
}
```

which will repeatedly call `CHECK` until `$status` is set to zero

***EXCEPT THAT*** you should *always* use lower-case characters in your local identifiers. Upper-case is reserved for global identifiers such as package names. In this situation you have unwittingly created a `CHECK` block

[`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) says this

> Five specially named code blocks are executed at the beginning and at the end of a running Perl program. These are the `BEGIN` , `UNITCHECK` , `CHECK` , `INIT` , and `END` blocks.
>
> These code blocks can be prefixed with sub to give the appearance of a subroutine (although this is not considered good style). One should note that these code blocks don't really exist as named subroutines (despite their appearance). The thing that gives this away is the fact that you can have more than one of these code blocks in a program, and they will get all executed at the appropriate moment. So you can't execute any of these code blocks by name.

So because *"these code blocks don't really exist as named subroutines"* your program will *only* call `CHECK` during compilation, and subsequent explicit calls will be ignored

So rename your subroutine to `check` and chnage your code to this

```
my $status = compare($b, $a);

if ( $status == 1 ) {

    do {
        CHECK;
    } until $status == 0;

    print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..";
    print "\n\t";
}
```

and all will be well

Comment: I already changed to "check"...it still stuck in the loop....What I want to happen is that subroutine will produce a zero result at the last part and maybe that can exit the loop...will that be possible sir?...I appreciate your help guys,...Im just a newbie on this language..

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why the until loop should stop.

In short, you get an md5 sum for a file in your "CHECK" sub.

```
sub CHECK {
    open (my $fh, '>', "/home/vivek/generated_mdsum_new.out");
    my $dump_file = "/home/vivek/file_dump.dmp";
    my $md5sum = `md5sum $dump_file`;
    my $value = (split(" ",$md5sum))[0];
    print $fh $value;
    close $fh;
    compare($a,$b); 
    # question: what is in $a / $b and what does compare do ?
}
```

Now you compare $a and $b and return that result.
Assuming $a / $b contain something useful, there is nothing in the until block or CHECK block that I see to change either, so the comparison would keep returning the same result ( assuming "compare" compares and does not change anything, which would be a bad naming if it did ).

So in the until block, do something to influence the CHECK, otherwise you are stuck in a loop.

Comment: the compare will compare the two mdsum files (which are $a $b)...if they are the same, it will give me a value of 0 (zero)..

Comment: right, so if status is not 0, what is going to happen to change that?

Comment: if not 0, it will copy the file from a remote location and do the checksum again. After that, it will compare until result is 0.

Comment: well, read answer above for an explanation for what the problem actually is, then :)

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* use lower-case characters in your local identifiers. Upper-case is reserved for global identifiers such as package names. In this situation you have unwittingly created a `CHECK` block

[`perldoc perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) says this

> Five specially named code blocks are executed at the beginning and at the end of a running Perl program. These are the `BEGIN` , `UNITCHECK` , `CHECK` , `INIT` , and `END` blocks.
>
> These code blocks can be prefixed with sub to give the appearance of a subroutine (although this is not considered good style). One should note that these code blocks don't really exist as named subroutines (despite their appearance). The thing that gives this away is the fact that you can have more than one of these code blocks in a program, and they will get all executed at the appropriate moment. So you can't execute any of these code blocks by name.

So because *"these code blocks don't really exist as named subroutines"* your program will *only* call `CHECK` during compilation. That means explicit calls to CHECK will be ignored, and `$status` never changes

Change your subroutine to `check` and all will be well

Comment: Does this really need to be repeated. ( You have two identical answers, and the other one has a relevant comment )

Comment: @BradGilbert: There is a bug in the Stack Overflow tablet app that sometimes duplicates a post instead of editing it. There is also no way that I can see to delete a post, so I have to wait until I get back to a PC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
until ($status == 0 ) {
    print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..";
    print "\n\t";
}
```

Nowhere in the loop are you changing the value of `$status`.

> The `"do CHECK;"` isn't part of the loop.
>  Would eval a file by the name of the return value of the `CHECK` sub
>  If it had actually called that sub.
>  Which it won't because it isn't actually a subroutine.

The other form of `until` is:

```
do {
   CHECK; # doesn't work as this is a special name
} until $status == 0;

print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..";
print "\n\t";
```

Which is still a problem as `CHECK` is a special name for a block that only gets called once at CHECK time, that you can't actually call.

Plus the code in `CHECK` would always have the same result, so calling it repeatedly doesn't make sense, and could still result in an infinite loop if it didn't work the first time.

---

## This is how I might have written it

This is a first pass of making your code make sense to me, also fixing some of the errors pointed out above.

I also changed `$a` and `$b` to `$ref` and `$new` since `$a` and `$b` are reserved variables.

I improved it by using modules that come with Perl, so that I don't have to check the return values of `open()` and `close()` ( [*autodie*](https://metacpan.org/pod/autodie) ), or rely on conventions of a particular platform ( [*Digest::MD5*](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::MD5), and [*File::Spec::Functions*](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Functions) ).

I assume that you loaded [*File::Compare*](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Compare).

I removed the setting of `$status` from the `check` sub to reduce the use of global variables.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1; # set minimum version which was released in 2009

use autodie;
use File::Spec::Functions qw' catfile catdir rootdir curdir ';
use Digest::MD5;
use File::Compare qw' compare ';

# should be // not ||, but it will work if your dir isn't named "0" or ""
my $basedir = $ENV{HOME} || catdir rootdir, qw' home vivek ';
# try the current directory if it doesn't exist
$basedir = curdir unless -d $basedir;

my $ref = catfile $basedir, 'generated_mdsum_reference.out';
my $new = catfile $basedir, 'generated_mdsum_new.out';

my $dumpfile = catfile $basedir, 'file_dump.dmp';

# forward declare so that we can put them at the end
sub md5_hex_file;
sub md5_sum;
sub check;

#-------------------------------------------------------

if ( compare($new, $ref) != 0 ){
    if ( check($dumpfile,$new) == 0 ){
        print "\n\tfiles are now Ok. Exiting..\n";
    } else {
        local $| = 1; # make sure the output is flushed to STDOUT
        print "\n\tfiles are NOT OK. Exiting..\n";
        exit 1;
    }
}

#-------------------------------------------------------

# helper subroutines

sub md5_hex_file {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    # let Digest::MD5 read the file for us
    my $ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
    { # limit scope of $fh
        open my $fh, '<', $filename;
        binmode $fh;
        $ctx->addfile( $fh );
        close $fh;
    }
    $ctx->hexdigest;
}

# no longer necessary
sub md5_sum {
    my ($filename) = @_;
    # `md5sum -b $filename`
    md5_hex_file($filename) . "  $filename\n";
}

sub check {
    my ( $infile, $outfile ) = @_

    print "\n" x 3, "\tGenerating MD5SUM ....\n";

    my $md5_hex = md5_hex_file $infile;

    print "\n" x 2, "Checksum: $md5_hex.\n";

    # Put checksum in file
    {
        open my $out_fh, '>', $outfile;
        print {$out_fh} $md5_hex;
        close $out_fh;
    }

    my $status = compare $new, $ref;
    return $status if $status == 0;


    # add a newline and hope that fixes it
    {
        open my $out_fh, '>>', $outfile;
        print {$out_fh} "\n";
        close $out_fh;
    }
    return compare $new, $ref;
}
```

---

Really I think you could have just used these "one-liners"

```bash
$ perl -Mautodie -MDigest::MD5 -e \
 'open $fh, q[<], shift;
  print Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest' \
file_dump.dmp > generated_mdsum_new.out

$ perl -MFile::Compare -e \
 'if ( compare(shift(),shift()) == 0 ){
    print qq[They match\n]
  } else {
    print qq[They don\'t match\n]
  }' \
generated_mdsum_new.out generated_mdsum_reference.out
```

Comment: Thanks to you guys...I'ts helping me a lot